# Difference between "cannot read property" and unable to get propert?

Tags: javascript, azure

In JS, what is the difference between "cannot read property X of undefined" and "unable to get property X of undefined"?

I'm getting these two different errors messages on an app I have deployed in Azure, and just noticed the differences in the message. Why are there two different error messages for potentially the same error? Is the origin of the errors not the same? Is it related to different libs, JS versions or OS?

Comment: What is the code generating these errors?

Comment: The first is a fairly standard error message using the phrasing of the V8 JavaScript engine (used in Chrome, Chromium, and NodeJS; different engines have different phrasing). I've never seen the second.

Comment: Chakra uses the second. https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22unable+to+get+property%22&type=Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean the same thing, it's just different phrasing. It means you've done something like:

```
console.log(a.X);
```

...where `a` has the value `undefined`:

```js
var a = undefined;
try {
  console.log(a.X);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
```

The first is the phrasing used by from Google's JS engine, V8, which is used in Chrome, Chromium, and NodeJS amongst others:

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/6eba6b4b89db81bc359dc041c62d1277f24bb8d4/src/messages.h#L334

The second is from Microsoft's engine, Chakra, which is used by IE and Edge.

https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/blob/58a7226c8eeb3993be19911d2711c147570eb3c2/lib/Parser/rterrors.h#L162

Comment: My mistake, I'm sure I *have* seen it, I just never quite noticed it. :-)